# Changing C++ output without changing the main() function

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
void main()
{
    cout<<"Love";
}
```

The question is how can we change the output of this program into 
"I Love You" without making any change in `main()`.

Comment: Even if this is cheating on homework, it's actually a question, you can learn something from, as demonstrated by litb's answer.

Comment: @Hanno: A great answer does not necessarily imply a great question.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The question doesn't need to be great (or even good) to be proper, though. I'm leaning toward re-opening this. Only, I'd prefer to fix it first, and I can't quite see the way...

Comment: @dmckee: Agreed. But I don't think the credit of litb's awesome answer should be given to the question at all.

Comment: Voted to re-open, it's clearly a real question.

Comment: http://www.digitalmars.com/archives/cplusplus/3663.html

Comment: Yeah, this is a real question.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I think its a cool question and a good one. It teaches how to execute some code before main function is called. You too didn't know how to do that, so it makes a good question for you also. So, would you stop complaining about the question?

Comment: raping RAII like i did, in the name of love, i would deserve being whipped by bjarne

Comment: `main` shall return `int`, and `iostream.h` does not exist.

Answer (score 91):

Ok, fixing your main function and iostream.h ... This is the way

```
#include <iostream>

// to make sure std::cout is constructed when we use it
// before main was called - thxx to @chappar
std::ios_base::Init stream_initializer;

struct caller {
    caller() { std::cout << "I "; }
    ~caller() { std::cout << " You"; }
} c;

// ohh well, for the br0ken main function
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Love";
}
```

I figured i should explain why that works. The code defines a structure that has a constructor and a destructor. The constructor is run when you create an object of the struct and the destructor is run when that object is destroyed. Now, at the end of a struct definition, you can put declarators that will have the type `caller`.

So, what we did above is creating an object called `c` which is constructed (and the constructor called) at program start - even before main is run. And when the program terminates, the object is destroyed and the destructor is run. In between, `main` printed "Love".

That pattern actually is very well known by the term `RAII` which usually claims some resource in the constructor and releases it again in the destructor call.

Comment: @Binu: But do you *why* it works? If you do, you've learned something significant about c++...

Comment: actually   i dont understand..dmckee
can u be more specific?

Comment: @Binu: Well, libt explained it. It's about *when* constructors and destructors run, and what the lifetime of `c` is. Try replacing "c;" with "c, d;" and see what happens...

Comment: You do deserve a Guru badge for this :)

Comment: @litb, The answer may not work in all the time. Is there any guarantee that cout will be constructed before your caller object? Does C++ standard mandates that cout, cin will be created before all the user global objects?

Comment: chappar, to my knowledge, there isn't any guarantee. you can however place an object of type ios_base::Init just before the struct definition.it has a counter.if it is zero, it will construct standard stream objects.In 27.3/2 however the std encourages implementations to construct them before main.

Comment: so, why don't you edit your answer? it will become more complete then!

Comment: chappar, i think you are right. i've put it in.

Comment: litb, your answer was great. it was made even complete and perfect by chappar. i think he deserves some credit as well, people are overlooking his contribution!

Comment: Mancs, indeed he's got a great idea making sure cout is already constructed. i'd give give him extra points on his comments if i only could!! Love You All :D:D

Comment: Thank you so much, the_drow :) I've read some days ago that C++1x guarantees that cout and friends are constructed after #include <iostream> is included. So we don't need the stream_initializer then anymore. Until that time, i'll keep it in, of course :P

Comment: that's just wrong! cool. but wrong!

Comment: Needs `std::cout` in `main`. :P

Answer (score 39):

```
#include <iostream>
class tclass
{
  public:
    void operator <<(char *s)
    {
          std::cout<<"I"<<s<<"You"<<std::endl;
    }
};

tclass cout;

int main()
{
  cout<<"love";
}
```

Comment: very clever, no need of doing it extraordinary way, do it the simple way, thats what you have done. this is as good as litb's answer if not as cool. very well done indeed!

Comment: Actually, it yields incorrect output.

Answer (score 13):

Not as elegant as litb's, but it works

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdio> 
#include <sstream> 

#define cout     printf("I love you\n"); std::ostringstream os; os 

int main() 
{ 
    cout << "love"; 
}
```

Of course, you don't need to use a `stringstream`, you could use any class with `operator<<`.

Answer (score 10):

Not as elegant as litb's, but an alternative:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int foo()
{
    cout << "I Love You" << endl;
    return cout.rdbuf(0);
}
int i = foo();

int main()
{
    cout << "Love" << endl;
}
```

Comment: what does rdbuf(0) do? does your program print "Love" after printing "I Love You"? If it does then, could we possibly terminate the program inside foo() without ever having to execute main() at all?

Comment: It hides the output of "Love" by redirecting cout to nothing.  It only prints "I Love You".

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   std::cout << "I Love You" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}

/*
#include<iostream.h>
void main()
{
    cout<<"Love";
}
*/
```

This way, you haven't changed anything in *the* `main`. :-p

Comment: What i meant is #include <iostream>
int main() {
   std::cout << "Love";
   return 0;
}

now.. change the output into I Love  You without making any change in main().

Comment: bad answer, not funny at all. if a 2 or 3 digit reputation holder posts this answer he'd get a -10 for it. thats SO double standard for you! :-)

Comment: @RealRed.: \[citation required\]

Answer (score 5):

We can do it like this too:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int fnfoo(int inum){
   cout << "I Love You" << endl;
   return (exit(0),inum);
}

int dummy = fnfoo(5);

int main()
{
   cout << "Love" << endl;
}
```

Simple and works perfectly ;)

Answer (score 2):

That code has no using std but anyway it would require writing your own wrapper around cout and removing the using std if there was and replace with using mystd where the wrapper is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could write an operator<< that added "I" before and "You" after the current output.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#define cout printf("I love you"); ostringstream os; os

/*newline*/
int main()
{
 cout << "love";
}

Comment: @rlbond erm, wouldn't that crash horribly because you're then doing printf(); << "love"; ? =D

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your main function return an int? You're either going to need to change the method, or write another program that this one pipes into, but that's the most round about way to change a simple string...

Comment: In C++ main() is an special function, and the only one allowed by the standard to declare a return type and not actually return anything (in which case the standard says that the compiler will perform as if a 0 was returned by the user)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It is, nonetheless, **required**
 to have a return type of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The lesson is that C++ can execute code before and after main() through static constructors/destructors, eg. the code posted by litb.

Comment: So your answer is "go look at that other answer over there"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this was a class assignment, I would bet the idea was that you could rewrite `iostream.h`, since C++ doesn't treat it as special (for certain definitions of "special").

Comment: If fact the standard does treat treat iostream (and all other standard headers) differently. The compiler is allowed to just inject the definitions in the code without actually including the header file. Then again, even if compilers are allowed to do it, most current implementations do not. Anyway, the use of angle brackets has concrete implications (with some compilers it will search for the files first in compiler and system wide directories, then locally), then again (again) other compilers just treat angle brackets and double quotes equally.

Comment: In other words "for certain definitions of 'special'."

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: But not `iostream.h`, which is not a part of the library.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the main, by either calling another function or by changing the text. Since `main()` is the main output of your program

Comment: -1 because this is not true.

Answer (score -1):

Can you be a little more precise?

You want the output of that piece of code to be "I love you" instead of "Love"?

Edit: I don't think you can't without changing at least one line of code in main(). You can either change from cout<<"Love" to cout<<"I love you" or just add a function that outputs that specific line.

Comment: yes..i need that output as you said..But the only condition is that there won't make even a single line code change in main().

Comment: Eh, you could define your own variable 'cout' in the global namespace, and have it print "I love you" to std::cout. :)

Answer (score -2):

I'm really surprised that noone suggested #define "Love" "I love you"... :)

Comment: This will not work since "Love" is a string and not an identifier or a symbolic name.