# How to "redefine" one char * to another char *?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Something like that: (it is task, how to do this, and not to change body of main function)

I thought that it is too simple... but... I don't know how to do it...

```
#include <iostream>

#define "a" "b"

int main( int argc,char ** argv) {
   std::cout << "a";
   return 0;
}
```

// output: b

How to do it?

Comment: Dare I ask why you want to commit such an unnatural act?

Comment: You can't. You're better off just using a simple if(for input). I don't think you can do anything with output, though.

Comment: Added `preprocessor` tag for relevance.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this?  The only thing I can think of is you have some very confused ideas about sub-string replacement or something.

Comment: `"a"` and `"b"` are not actually of type `char*`; they are both of type `const char[2]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Changing C++ output without changing the main() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646169/changing-c-output-without-changing-the-main-function)

for example from that topic:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdio> 
#include <sstream> 

#define cout     printf("a"); std::ostringstream os; os 

int main() 
{ 
    std::cout << "b"; 
}
```

a simplier one:

```
#include <iostream>
#define cout cout << "a"; return 0; std::cout
int main() 
{ 
    std::cout << "b"; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in printf

Comment: Over time I've come to believe that, in C++, "impossible" is always only a temporary answer to any problem someone needs solved. In 80% of all cases, someone comes along and bends templates, macros, and some of those "features" we would get along quite well without to their purpose, thereby achieving what everybody thought was, indeed, absolutely impossible. I bow, though slightly shuddering, before this idea. May you live long and may your code never cross my path.

Answer (score 8):

Fortunately, you can't redefine string literals. Of course, the real question is: *why* do you want to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Macro names must be identifiers, and thus cannot contain the character `"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The preprocessor doesn't "look into" string literals.

Comment: @mr. Vachovsky: What problem? The "problem" that the code can be read and understood without running it through the preprocessor?

Comment: @mr. this isn't a _problem_, what are you trying to do? You can always `cout << "b";`

Comment: @mr. Vachovsky: That's the problem with your question. You haven't stated any problem. You've just come to ask how to solve it in a way it can't be solved. Tell us __why__ you think you need to have `"a"` printed as `"b"`, and we might be able to help you solving your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to do this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define a "b"

int main( int argc,char ** argv) {
   std::cout << a;
   return 0;
}
```

Output :  `b`

Answer (score 0):

`#define` is a bad `c++` style. Use `const`.

```
#include <iostream>  
// const char * string_a = "a"; // Regular: Use const char *
const char * string_a = "b"; // Replacing: Instead of bad    #define "a" "b"  

int main( int argc,char ** argv) {    
    std::cout << string_a;    
    return 0; 
}
```